# Необходима запятая или точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, точка-с-запятой

Предложение: "Джилмен знал, конечно, что живёт в пресловутом Ведьмином доме; собственно, именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату".

Правильно ли я понимаю, что употребление точки с запятой здесь можно рассматривать исключительно как факультативное? Словом, хочет автор – ставит, не хочет – ограничивается обычной запятой?

Comment: Ольга, спасибо за доверие! Вероятно, еще будут возражения и альтернативные решения вопроса. Главное, что хочу отметить, это то, что переводчик не ошибся, он не обязан следовать пунктуации источника. Точка с запятой не противоречит правилам. Просто, с точки зрения грамматики и семантики, хотелось бы большей ясности. Еще раз: вторая часть имеет пояснительно-присоединительный смысл. Не имеет значения длительность паузы (это очень субъективно, ведь у всех разный темп речи и никто не замеряет секундомером эти паузы). Здесь могут быть следующие знаки: точка, многоточие, тире, скобки.

Comment: Если принять "мою" пунктуацию (запятая, тире), то ни один редактор не прикопается: запятая закрывает изъяснительное придаточное к первому предложению, к тому же вводное слово должно выделяться с обеих сторон. А самый, по-моему, оптимальный вариант – это скобки: *Джилмен знал, конечно, что живет в пресловутом Ведьмином доме (собственно, именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату).*

Comment: Cпасибо за такой обстоятельный подход! Развернувшееся обсуждение многое добавило в мою "копилку".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если поставить просто запятую, это предложение, на мой взгляд, будет плохо "смотреться" и плохо читаться. Точка с запятой отделяет две фразы, первая из которых — сложноподчиненное предложение, а вторая имеет присоединительный оттенок (ее можно даже в скобки заключить). К тому же обе фразы имеют свои вводные слова. Пунктуация должна четко обозначить паузу, а вводное слово ***собственно*** должно без колебаний относиться ко второй части. Точка с запятой благополучно справляется с этим.

Я бы вообще оформил так:

***Джилмен знал, конечно, что живет в пресловутом Ведьмином доме, — собственно, именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату.***

Ориентируюсь на правила Розенталя ([**Вводные слова и словосочетания**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122)):

> 10. Тире при вводных словах (сочетаниях) употребляется в следующих случаях:
> <...>
> 2) перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям: *Собака исчезла, — **наверно**, её убили* (Слепц.); *Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — **верно**, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады* (Пан.); *Но Супругов был занят папиросой, которая почему-то потухла, — **должно быть**, гильза была рваная* (Пан.); *Кучерявый… смотрел ему на лоб с выражением отвлечённого интереса, словно решал в уме задачу, — **казалось**, сейчас вынет из-за уха карандаш, из кармана блокнот и запишет решение* (Пан.).

P. S. По большому счету, пауза ничем и никем не регламентирована. Вместо точки с запятой может стоять даже точка.

Comment: Да, запятая здесь не подойдет — пауза явно больше, чем при запятой, но меньше, чем при постановке точки. А вот выбор мне представляется таким: точка с запятой, а также простое тире или единый знак запятая и тире. (Формальное решение, связанное с вводным словом, мне не очень нравится.) А вот каждый из трех знаков имеет свою интонацию, а также разные семантические оттенки... Вот здесь уже есть над чем подумать.

Comment: Слово «фраза» в русском языке означает законченное высказывание. Т. е. это то, что кто-то говорит. Например,  *«Его короткие, лающие фразы возбуждали у матери недоумение, а последние слова вызвали зависть».* Горький Максим, Мать. В приведённом примере вообще нет фраз. Вы используете английское толкование слова, распространённое сейчас в Интернете из-за неправильного перевода. Phrase — а small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit, typically forming a component of a clause ([Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/phrase)).

Comment: @Eagle  Всё верно. Фраза – это отрезок речи, законченное высказывание с законченной интонацией. Также фраза и предложение часто являются синонимами. В том месте, где стоит точка с запятой можно поставить точку: будет две фразы или два самостоятельных предложения. Никакое английское толкование я не использую.

Comment: По вашей ссылке дальше написано: «Дополнительный знак препинания может подчеркивать причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения». В приведенных примерах тире создаёт впечатление причинно-следственности, какого-то заключения: «Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили», «куда-то засмотрелась… — верно, в свои… сады», «почему-то потухла, — должно быть, гильза была рваная», «смотрел ему на лоб… словно решал в уме задачу, — казалось, сейчас вынет… карандаш… запишет решение». А слово «собственно (говоря)» выражает, ни следствие, ни заключение, а способ выражения мысли.

Comment: Из словаря РАН Евгеньевой: ФРА́ЗА, -ы, ж. **1. Законченное высказывание.** *Запивая каждую фразу чаем с ромом ---, он рассказывал о своих успехах на сцене.* Чехов, Первый любовник. *«Жалко папу» — вот ясная, отчетливая фраза, которая болью охватывала сердца детей.* Гарин-Михайловский, Детство Темы. **Высказывание — в лингвистике, предложение в конкретной речевой ситуации** ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Фраза — это продолжение кем-то высказанное. *«Жалко папу» — вот ясная, отчетливая фраза...*

Comment: @Eagle И что? Где противоречия? Давайте не будем об этом. Высказываются мнения, например, что части сложного предложения нельзя называть предложениями. Всё это не стоит обсуждения в данном вопросе. P. S. Запятая после тире – нонсенс. На другие комментарии я отвечу, скорее всего, завтра.

Comment: @Eagle  Я считаю, что в большей степени здесь имеют место именно присоединительные отношения.

Comment: Это не тире. В условных обозначениях этого словаря «---» — сокращение в цитатах. В произведении полное предложение: «Положив ногу на ногу, запивая каждую фразу чаем с ромом и стараясь придать своему лицу небрежно-скучающее выражение, он рассказывал о своих успехах на сцене». В словаре сокращают, наверное, чтоб экономить место и не загружать читателя лишним текстом, не существенным для понимания контекста использования слова.

Comment: Начёт фразы, я всё-таки хотел бы разобраться со значением этого термина. Я задал [данный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464543/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Мне ответили: «Предложение — это письменная единица, фраза — устная и выделяется интонацией». Так что я скорей всего прав.

Answer (score 2):

**Это не ответ, а комментарий**

Александр, мне нравятся ваши ответы и всегда приятно их видеть – я уверена, что вам есть что нам сказать. К сожалению, мне никто не ответил на мои комментарии, тем не менее мне хотелось бы поделиться с вами, а также с обществом определенной информацией по обсуждаемой теме. У меня остались такие вопросы.

1. **О паузах**

Вы не доверяете паузам, они зависят от **темпа произношения**? Безусловно, да, в этом вы правы.  В то же время паузы теснее, чем мы думаем, связаны с другой фонетикой – ударением прежде всего. В принципе любая пауза (остановка голоса) предполагает  выделение более значимых слов в предшествующем тексте – к тому же это тоническое ударение, то есть **повышение или понижение** голоса.  Здесь, как мне думается, тонкая регуляция, плавный переход.

А  вот это носители языка **уже чувствуют** даже при разном темпе произношения и незаметных паузах, и эта семантика для нас важна.

2. **О вводных словах на границе двух простых предложений в составе сложного**

У Розенталя:  Перед вводным словом в качестве **дополнительного** знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и **по смыслу** может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям: *Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили.*

**Дополнительный** знак препинания может **подчеркивать** причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения: *Проверить его слова было трудно, — **очевидно**, обстоятельства сильно изменились.*

Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на выделенные слова.

А вот **другие варианты** оформления у того же Розенталя:

п. 12 *Прозвенел звонок, **значит,**  урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, **значит**, пеняйте на самого себя.*

п. 13. *Чапаев никогда не отказывался от вмешательства в подобные дела; **наоборот**, он любил разобрать всё сам.*

Пример из Справочника по пунктуации: *Послал он мне крест – **значит**, меня он любит.* И. Тургенев, Живые мощи.

Всё это разрешенные правилами варианты, и у каждого свои особенности, **свои семантические оттенки**, вот их надо хорошо различать при выборе знака.

3. **Точка с запятой  для обозначения присоединительных отношений**

*Джилмен знал, конечно, что живет в пресловутом Ведьмином доме; **собственно,** именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату.*

При таком оформлении мы **не подчеркиваем** причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения, точка с запятой и так обозначает их **присоединительный** характер  (в этом плане этот знак есть нечто среднее между точкой и присоединительной запятой).

А вот **тире** останавливает наше внимание (сильный знак!), и оно именно подчеркнет присоединительный вид отношений, хотя в этом **нет особой необходимости.**

4. **Еще раз о едином знаке**

Как различить **независимое сочетание**  запятой и тире от единого знака?  Чисто визуально (на письме) это сделать нельзя, нужно анализировать предложение. Но сначала мы просто **видим** знак – читатель же и вовсе не будет заниматься анализом.

И если все-таки вспомнить **о едином знаке** (о нем, правда, никто и думать не хочет, но он все-таки существует,  вопреки всеобщему недоверию к себе), то у читателя могут возникнут ассоциации **с еще более сильным знаком,** вот поэтому мне **не хотелось** бы его здесь видеть. В небольших по объему предложениях он кажется  каким-то «нескромным», кричащим и требующим к себе повышенного внимания. По крайней мере, мне так кажется, может быть, я и не права.

5. **Когда ставится точка с запятой**

Обычно в качестве причины называются **формальные и хорошо видимые признаки** – распространенность предложений и собственные знаки препинания.

Но есть и еще одна причина, о которой не стоит забывать, – это **отдаленность тематики.** И вот она мне представляется наиболее существенной, так как другие  признаки  скорее связаны с этой семантикой.

Примеры из классических произведений:

*Мы поехали; заря только что разгорелась* (И.С. Тургенев). *Солнце только что начинало подниматься из-за туч; в воздухе было свежо и росисто* (Л. Н.Толстой).

**ВЫВОД**  (для заданного предложения)

**Запятую** ставить нельзя, так как необходимо **смысловое разграничение** двух частей сложного предложения (с тремя предикативными основами). Кстати, это еще одна **функция** точки с запятой.

**Запятая и тире**  выглядит как **избыток знаков** препинания в небольшом по объему предложении.

Мое оформление было бы только таким:

*Джилмен знал, конечно, что живет в пресловутом Ведьмином доме;  **собственно,** именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату.*

Обозначен присоединительный характер  второй части.

**Примечание**

Неплохо бы смотрелся вариант **с одним тире** (тогда были бы обозначены причинно-следственные отношения между двумя частями сложного предложения), но здесь нужно **закрывать запятой** придаточное предложение.

Я бы эту закрывающую запятую **не ставила бы** – и так все красиво, понятно и интонационно обозначено, но корректоры могут не пропустить, им же формальность нужна.  А без запятой это будет АВТОРСКАЯ пунктуация:

Джилмен знал, конечно, что живет в пресловутом Ведьмином доме – **собственно**, именно поэтому он и снял здесь комнату.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!  Ваше мнение и ваша поддержка для меня всегда много значат, но в данный момент важны особенно.

Comment: Минусуют даже комментарии – вот интересно, они-то кому помешали?  Что там предосудительного или неверного?  Обозначьте уж свою позицию,  интересно будет послушать. Предъявляете ко мне очень высокие требования по качеству любого текста? Тогда и я буду предъявлять к вам такие же высокие требования.

Comment: Sharon, я тоже поставил плюс за ваш труд, анализ и неравнодушие. А что значит "минусуют комментарии"? Вы имеете в виду флажок?

Comment: Я имела в виду:  18.31 – голос против.  Александр, я  ни в коем случае не думала на вас, вы на это по своей природе не способны, есть такие люди.  Труд, анализ и неравнодушие…  Знаете, я во всем, что связано с темой интонационного анализа, чувствую всё ту же атмосферу, слышу один и тот же диалог, о котором уже говорила раньше: «Хотите, я научу вас летать? – «Да иди ты куда подальше!»  Эмоционально это еще напрягает, конечно, но  уже пройденный этап, я стала другой…

Comment: @Sharon, минусуют те, кто не не может обосновать свою точку зрения.

Comment: Согласна, Серж, но будем надеяться, что не они здесь главные.

Answer (score 0):

Это отрывок из произведения «Сны в ведьмином доме» Говарда Филлипса Лавкрафта.

Оригинал на английском, и то, что вы привели это перевод на русский.

Такую пунктуацию сделал не автор, а переводчик.

У автора это предложение выглядит так:

> He knew his room was in the old Witch-House—that, indeed, was why he
> had taken it.
>
> Он знал, что его комната находится в старом Ведьмином доме, и именно
> поэтому он её и выбрал.

Пунктуация автора вообще совершенно другая. То, что у вас — пунктуация переводчика.

Переводчик, видимо, руководствовался правилом ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134)):

> 1. Если части сложносочиненного предложения значительно распространены
>    (часто это сложные предложения смешанного типа — с сочинением,
>    подчинением и бессоюзной связью) и имеют внутри себя запятые, то между
>    такими частями ставится точка с запятой.
>    ...
> 2. Постановка точки с запятой в некоторых случаях факультативна.

В предложении уже есть несколько запятых, и переводчик, видимо, чтоб не было путаницы при чтении, поставил точку с запятой.
Обратите внимание, что написано: «Постановка точки с запятой в некоторых случаях факультативна».

Comment: Розенталь предлагает два возможных решения, расскажите нам, как сделать выбор, иначе нет ответа.

Comment: Я вот тоже  говорю о «факультативности». Можно встретить на форуме такие ответы: здесь нужно поставить двоеточие, но можно заменить тире, да и запятая допускается.  Ну да, всё перебрали, разве что про точку с многоточием не вспомнили.  В классической литературе мне встречались предложения, состоящие из двух слов, а после стояла точка с запятой, обратите внимание. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, такой вариант.

Comment: И хорошие переводчики знаки ставят тоже со смыслом, а не абы как. Пунктуация в английском языке  - это вообще вещь в себе, лучше о ней без надобности не вспоминать. Так что вы уж русский текст анализируйте,  мы ведь русским языком занимаемся. Также по поводу «фразы». Вам еще раз поискать учебник с определением терминов или уж сами справитесь? Интернет же есть, наберите в поисковике и читайте, дело-то простое.

Comment: @Sharon Насчёт фразы поищите. Я задал [данный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464543/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Мне ответили: «Предложение — это письменная единица, фраза — устная и выделяется интонацией». Так что я скорей всего прав.

Comment: Вам отвечать себе дороже. Вы же любой ответ переиначите, чтобы убедить себя, а также  других в своей правоте. Именно это для вас самоцель? Лучше перенастройте себя на поиск истины, это можно как-нибудь сделать?
Про фразу по ссылке  прочитайте, мне интересно, какой вы сделаете вывод. https://studopedia.su/17_91161_fraza-sintagma.html  Будете правым или нет?  Мне кажется, что вероятность фифти-фифти. Кстати, теория в области фонетики и грамматики сейчас меняется быстро, а уж за последние 50 лет с момента выхода вашего словаря изменилась значительно. Уж лучше вам расстаться с ним.

Comment: Зачем предлагать пунктуацию источника? Пунктуация в двух языках во многом отличается.

Comment: @Серж Я не предлагал использовать пунктуацию источника. С чего вы взяли? Исходя из вопроса человека, я сделал вывод, что человеку не понятно, почему автор поставил точку с запятой, а не запятую, и было ли это желание автора, или есть такое обязательное правило. Я просто указал на то, что в отличие от, Льва Толстого, например, которого мы читаем в оригинале и можем судить об авторской пунктуации, тут мы читаем перевод, и это пунктуация переводчика, и никакого отношения точка с запятой к решению автора о пунктуации не имеет. Я вообще не пойму, что в этом людям не нравится, и почему это возмущает

Comment: Ну ведь это и так понятно. Здесь переводной текст, следовательно, пунктуация языка-перевода.