# Фраза и предложение: в чём разница?

Tags: значение-слов, терминология, термины

Если взять, например, словарь русского языка РАН Евгеньевой:

> ПРЕДЛОЖЕ́НИЕ, -я, ср.
>
> 1. Грамм. Высказывание, являющееся сообщением о чем-л.
>    Простое предложение. Сложное предложение. Придаточное предложение.

> ФРА́ЗА, -ы, ж.
>
> 1. Законченное высказывание.
>    *Запивая каждую фразу чаем с ромом ---, он рассказывал о своих успехах  > на сцене.* Чехов, Первый любовник. *«Жалко
>    папу» — вот ясная, отчетливая фраза, которая болью охватывала сердца
>    детей.* Гарин-Михайловский, Детство Темы.

Если, и то и то, является высказыванием. И то и то является законченным высказыванием.

В чём же всё-таки разница? Что в языкознании считается фразой, а что предложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение кончается точкой (вопросительным знаком и т.д.), а фраза — это законченная мысль, не привязанная к пунктуации. Предложение может состоять из нескольких фраз. Бывает и обратное.
Это первое.
Второе. Предложение — это письменная единица, фраза — устная и выделяется интонацией.
[Фраза. Большая российская энциклопедия](https://bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/4735253)

Comment: Да. По вашей ссылки написано: *«Смы­сло­вое един­ст­во, це­ло­ст­ность ко­то­ро­го соз­да­ёт­ся **ин­то­на­ци­он­ны­ми сред­ст­ва­ми** (объ­е­ди­няю­щей фра­зо­вой ин­то­на­ци­ей то­го или ино­го ти­па и пау­за­ми, от­де­ляю­щи­ми дан­ную Ф. от со­сед­них)».* Письменная речь не имеет интонации, поэтому, исходя из того, что написано, фраза — это устная речь, то, что кем-то сказано.